# serverside recaptcha v2 validation

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am trying to implement Google recaptcha v2 which is the one with '
I am not a robot' and you have to click on the images eg: fire hydrant.

The frontend is working correctly but I can't get the server side code right.

I tried this in my current validation but even after completing the recaptcha correctly I still get the validation error message I set.

```
        $secretKey = 'MY_SECRET_KEY';
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secretKey.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']); 
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData !== 'success') {
            $message .= 'Invalid captcha';
        }


        if(!empty($message)) {

            $response['success'] = false;
            $response['message'] = $message;
        } else {

         //success
```

When logging $responseData to the console I get:

```
{success: true, challenge_ts: "2019-07-11T17:11:20Z", hostname: "example.com"}
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of `$responseData` in the body of your question?

Comment: @esqew, sure. I have updated the question.

Comment: Any particular reason you're comparing (what seems to be) an object to a string (`'success'`)? It's extremely unlikely the response you'll get from `json_decode()`ing will ever be a simple string like that.

Comment: I tried `if($responseData['success'] !== 'true') {` but it's giving me a server error

Comment: That's because, based on your example, `$responseData` should be a PHP object, not an associative array. You'd use the property get/set syntax to retrieve the `success` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for [`json_decode()`](https://php.net/json_decode) clearly state the following about what it returns:

> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values
>   true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL
>   respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the
>   encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

You shouldn't be comparing the return value of `json_decode()` to a string (in the example you provided, `'success'`). Instead, access the value inside the object in the normal [PHP property getter/setter notation syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php):

```
if(!$responseData->success) {
    $message .= 'Invalid captcha';
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay.  I am guessing I should change that to `if(!$responseData->success)` as I only want the validation failed message if the captcha is not completed?

Comment: @user8463989 That's correct. I've updated my answer to reflect this small change.